# Check if me.userform is still open?

Tags: vba, loops, optimization, userform

I'm having an issue with a userform that has a do while loop running in it's code. When I close the userform , the loop is still trying to run, and causes errors.  Look at this code from a userform  with only one button

```
   Private Sub btnWait_Click()
         Dim TenDays As Date
         TenDays = DateAdd("d", 10, Now) 'Set a date for 10 days in the future
         Do While Now < TenDays
              'just wait
              DoEvents
         Loop

         MsgBox ("Did you really wait ten days to see if this would work?")
    End Sub
```

Run the form, and click the button - Nothing will happen
But if I close the userform, The VBA editor is still in run mode, as the loop is still active (and I assume will be for over a week)

would it be better to include something like this in the loop

```
         Do While Now < TenDays
              'just wait
              if me.isClosed then exit sub  ' What Real code would work here?
              DoEvents
         Loop
```

Or to try and handle it when closing the form like this...?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    me.FindRunningloopsandExitThem ' What would this sub look like?
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: What is DoEvents?

Comment: @SEarle1986 it lets the host process process its message queue, so that the one & only available thread isn't stuck wasting cycles (and nothing else) for 10 days.

Comment: why does it require a while loop?

Comment: Because the OP doesn't know better? AFAIK it *doesn't*.

Comment: I stripped away all the other things that would happen during the do while loop on my actual project, so we could look at only the question at hand - Let's face it, this sub as it's written now it perfectly useless.

In the real sub, its checking details on contact items while in the background, while the user continues to interact with the userform.  This is the only simple way that I know of to get VBA to emulate a multithreading environment.  Is there a better option?